# Java not writing to file correctly

Tags: java, linux, io, runtime-error, irc

Here is my output:

```
/channel #blarg123
chanswitch: #blarg123
hello
----->PRIVMSG #blarg123 :hello
----->Logging: -->:phyrrus92 :hai ]
Error open
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at irc_channel_obj.writemsg(irc_channel.java:66)
    at irc_channel.sendmsg(irc_channel.java:24)
    at irc.irc_log(irc.java:28)
    at irc.main(irc.java:91)
```

I don't understand why it is throwing this exception, because all of the code seems to be correct and the file exists (./#blarg123)

Here is the code:

```
File: irc.java

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

class irc
{
    static Socket server;
    static BufferedReader in;
    static BufferedReader stdin;
    static PrintWriter out;
    static String channel;
    static irc_channel chanlist;

    public static void irc_log(String line)
    {
            System.out.println("----->Logging: " + line);
            String[] splitted = line.split(" ");
            String channel = "", sendline = "";
            if (splitted[0].indexOf("!") != -1)
                    splitted[0] = splitted[0].substring(0, splitted[0].indexOf("!"));
            for (int i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++)
            {
                    sendline += splitted[i];
                    if (splitted[i].indexOf("#") != -1)
                    {
                            channel = splitted[i];
                    }
            }
            chanlist.sendmsg(channel, sendline);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
            String user_line;
            channel = "none";
            chanlist = new irc_channel();
            try
            {
                    server = new Socket(args[0], 6667);
                    in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream()) );
                    stdin = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in) );
                    out = new PrintWriter(server.getOutputStream());
            }
            catch (UnknownHostException e) {}
            catch (IOException e) {}
            irc_in input = new irc_in(server, out, stdin);
            Thread t = new Thread(input);
            t.start();
            while (true)
            {
                    try {
                            user_line = in.readLine();
                            String[] splitted = user_line.split(" ");
                            if (splitted[0].equals("PING"))
                            {
                                    out.print("PONG " + splitted[1] + "\r\n");
                                    out.flush();
                                    continue;
                            }
                            boolean chan_filtered = false;
                            if (splitted[0].indexOf("!") != -1)
                            {
                                    splitted[0] = "" + splitted[0].substring(0, splitted[0].indexOf("!"));
                            }
                            for (int i = 1; i < splitted.length && !chan_filtered; i++)
                            {
                                    if (splitted[i].equals(channel))
                                    {
                                            chan_filtered = true;
                                            user_line = "\u001B[0;32m-->" + splitted[0] + " ";
                                            for (int x = 3; x < splitted.length; x++)  //x=i
                                            {
                                                    user_line += splitted[x] + " ";
                                            }
                                            user_line += "\u001B[0m]";
                                    }
                                    else if (splitted[i].indexOf("#") != -1)
                                    {
                                            chan_filtered = true;
                                            user_line = "\u001B[0;31m-->" + splitted[0] + " ";
                                            for (int x = 2; x < splitted.length; x++) //x=i
                                            {
                                                    user_line += splitted[x] + " ";
                                            }
                                            user_line += "\u001B[0m]";
                                    }
                            }
                            if (!channel.equals("none"))
                            {
                                    irc_log(user_line);
                                    //chanlist.displayall(channel);
                            }
                            //else
                            {
                                    System.out.println(user_line);
                                    System.out.flush();
                            }
                            //Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (IOException e) {}
            }
    }
}

class irc_in implements Runnable
{
    static Socket server;
    static PrintWriter out;
    static BufferedReader stdin;

    irc_in(Socket a, PrintWriter b, BufferedReader c)
    {
            server = a;
            out = b;
            stdin = c;
    }

    public void run()
    {
            String user_line;
            while (true)
            {
                    try
                    {
                            //Thread.sleep(1000);
                            user_line = stdin.readLine();
                            String[] splitted=user_line.split(" ");
                            if (splitted[0].equals("/channel") || splitted[0].equals("/JOIN"))
                            {
                                    user_line = "";
                                    splitted[0] = splitted[0].substring(1, splitted[0].length());
                                    for (int i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++)
                                            user_line += splitted[i] + " ";
                                    irc.channel = splitted[1];
                                    System.out.println("chanswitch: " + irc.channel);
                                    if (splitted[0].equals("channel"))
                                            continue;
                            }

                            else if (splitted[0].equals("/setname") && splitted.length >= 2)
                            {
                                    String user_name = "";
                                    for (int i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++)
                                            user_name += splitted[i];
                                    out.print("NICK " + splitted[1] + "\r\n");
                                    out.print("USER " + splitted[1] + " * 8 : " + user_name + "\r\n");
                                    out.flush();
                            }

                            else if (!splitted[0].startsWith("/"))
                            {
                                    int startpos = 0;
                                    String send_channel = irc.channel;
                                    if (splitted[0].startsWith("#"))
                                    {
                                            send_channel = splitted[0];
                                            startpos = 1;
                                    }
                                    user_line = "PRIVMSG " + send_channel + " :";
                                    for (int i = startpos; i < splitted.length; i++)
                                            user_line += splitted[i] + " ";
                                    System.out.println("----->" + user_line);
                            }

                            else
                                    user_line = user_line.substring(1, user_line.length());

                            out.print(user_line + "\r\n");
                            out.flush();
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {}
            }
    }
}
```

And another file

```
File: irc_channel.java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class irc_channel
{
    public static ArrayList<irc_channel_obj> list;

    irc_channel()
    {
            list = new ArrayList<irc_channel_obj>();
    }

    public void sendmsg(String channel, String line)
    {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
            {
                    if (list.get(i).name.equals(channel))
                    {
                            list.get(i).writemsg(line);
                            return;
                    }
            }
            irc_channel_obj newchan = new irc_channel_obj(channel);
            newchan.writemsg(line);
            list.add(newchan);
    }

    public void displayall(String channel)
    {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
            {
                    if (list.get(i).name.equals(channel))
                    {
                            list.get(i).displayall();
                            return;
                    }
            }
            System.out.println("No messages for channel " + channel);
    }
}

class irc_channel_obj
{
    public static String name;
    static PrintWriter out;
    static BufferedReader in;

    irc_channel_obj(String chan)
    {
            name = chan;
            try
            {
                    out = new PrintWriter(name);
                    out.println("Channel: " + name);
                    out.flush();
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                    System.out.println("Error open");
                    return;
            }
    }

    public void writemsg(String line)
    {
            out.println(line);
            out.flush();
    }

    public void displayall()
    {
            String line = "";
            try
            {
                    in = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(name) );
                    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                            System.out.println(line);
                    }
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) { return; }
            catch (IOException e) { return; }
    }
}
```

Any help would be amazing.

Comment: which is line 66 in `irc_channel.java`?

Comment: @jlordo it is the blank line before the function name

Comment: out is throwing the null pointer

Comment: @phyrrus9: I did a copy&paste. Line 66 is `out.println(line);`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant part of your output:

```
Error open
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at irc_channel_obj.writemsg(irc_channel.java:66)
```

`Error open` means that your `irc_channel_obj` constructor threw a `FileNotFoundException`. That's why `out` stays `null`.

Later, in `writemsg(String line)` you call

```
out.println(line);
```

where `out` is still `null` --> `NullPointerException`.

Comment: I knew that much. The problem is WHY did it throw that exception

Comment: Because [`new PrintWriter(String filename)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter(java.lang.String)) throws a `FileNotFoundException` if the given string does not denote an existing, writable regular file and a new regular file of that name cannot be created, or if some other error occurs while opening or creating the file.

Comment: @phyrrus9: To find out what's really happening replace `System.out.println("Error open");` with `e.printStackTrace();`.

Comment: I found the problem, it was in the irc_log function, it is not sending the channel name. Now we need to fix that

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was actually the placement of log, it needed to be moved to right under the readline from the server, since log was looking for a channel that had already been removed from the list.